# Oracle provider for .NET - Not working with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, oracle, visual-studio-2012, odp.net

I'm trying to work on a existing ASP.NET project which use Oracle databases. I encountered some issues when it came to run the project. At the edmx level, Visual Studio displays an error message :

> The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration.

Here is the underlined part :

```
 <edmx:StorageModels>
      <Schema Namespace="Model1.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" ProviderManifestToken="10.2" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl">
        <EntityContainer Name="Model1StoreContainer">
          <EntitySet Name="PIVOT_GRID_LAYOUTS" EntityType="Model1.Store.PIVOT_GRID_LAYOUTS" store:Type="Tables" Schema="HR_DWH" />
        </EntityContainer>
        <EntityType Name="PIVOT_GRID_LAYOUTS">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="ID" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="ID" Type="number" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="NT_ACCOUNT" Type="varchar2" MaxLength="255" />
          <Property Name="PIVOTGRID_NAME" Type="varchar2" MaxLength="255" />
          <Property Name="LAYOUT_STRING" Type="varchar2" />
          <Property Name="LAYOUT_NAME" Type="varchar2" MaxLength="255" />
          <Property Name="LAYOUT_STRING_CLOB" Type="clob" />
        </EntityType>
      </Schema>
    </edmx:StorageModels>
```

After research, I understood that I had to install the ODP.NET components in order to use Oracle databases in my Visual Studio application.

So I installed Oracle 11g R2 (x86) and then the ODAC 11.2.0.3. I thought it would be enough to make the things work but apparently it is not.

Any lead on that? I kinda followed lots of tutorials but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I think the provider name is `Oracle.DataAccess`, not `Oracle.DataAccess.Client`

Comment: Still the same issue ...